# what data structure should I use to store binary codes in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, binary, image-compression

I have binary codes as **10111** , **100011**, **11101111** etc. now what **data structure** should I use to store these codes so that minimum size is required to store them?

I can't use **string array** as size required will be more as compared than storing the decimal equivalent of above binary codes.

Comment: Store them in normal integers? or `byte` if you are looking for minimum capacity.

Comment: How long can these bit strings be? Have you considered the obvious answer of `int` or `long`?

Comment: If you use Integer or Long you can do this later: `Integer.toBinaryString(intValue);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`java.util.BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) is designed for that if the length is not fixed.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the length of the codes, simply use `int` or `long`.

Comment: if we store 10 in integer, 4 bytes will be required where as binary of 10 is 1010 which require 4 bits so how do I store 10 as binary with minimum size?

Comment: If you want to store 10b into the integer use `int code=0b10` (only java >=1.7) or `Integer.parseInt("10", 2);` (every version)

Answer (score 3):

If they'll be short, use `byte`, `int`, `long` (depending on how short).

If they'll be a bit longer, use an array of `byte`s, `int`s, or `long`s. For instance, if you need to store a 256-bit code, you can do that in a `long[4]`.

If the length of the codes you need to store varies widely, you might consider either a class with a `length` member giving the number of bits and a `byte`, `int`, `long`, `byte[]`, `int[]`, or `long[]` member for storing them (depending on sizes and what kind of granularity you want). Or if you're really trying to pack as much in as you can, you can set aside some of the bits from your storage area to hold the number of bits in the code.

Comment: If a long[] is needed BitSet is really the better choice since it manages a long[] for you with convenience functions for accessing the bits

Comment: @ptriller: Yeah. I added a link to the docs for it to your answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Each binary code could be split in portions by 8 bits (a byte). It would be necessary to define how to handle the tail if it is less than 8 bits. Byte arrays should work here nicely to store each portion.